# Is There A Difference Between targetCompatability And Running Gradle With That JDK?

Tags: java, gradle

I need to compile and run my jar with JDK7.

However, the gradle plugins I am using fail if I try to run gradle with JDK7.

I have specified the source and target in the build.gradle:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
```

If I run the build with JDK8 will the bytecode look the same as if I ran the build with JDK7?

Comment: Did you get any error message? Othwerwise I can recommend this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732290/java-cross-compilation-benefits-of-latest-jdk) about java cross compilation.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that there is a typo in your question (re: "compatability"). You'll want this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

I have created a working illustration [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64489426). Though not necessary, it is easier to test when using a tool such as [SDK Man!](https://sdkman.io/) (to switch JDKs easily).

#### Experiment **without** using the flags:

- use JDK 8 (e.g. `sdk use java 8u131`)
- edit `build.gradle` so that compatibility flags are commented out
- `gradle clean compileJava`
- switch to JDK 7 (e.g. `sdk use java 7.0.181-zulu`)
- run the code (see `./run.sh`)

  - this should fail, because it is built as JDK 8 (error below)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Example : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

#### Experiment **with** the flags:

- use JDK 8 (e.g. `sdk use java 8u131`)
- edit `build.gradle` so that compatibility flags are **enabled**
- `gradle clean compileJava`
- switch to JDK 7 (e.g. `sdk use java 7.0.181-zulu`)
- run the code (see `./run.sh`)

  - this should work, because of the compatibility flags

Comment: There is no JDK8 specific code involved so it won't fail as you mention. The question is more about the comment that mentions cross compilation.